# How to play yeti level

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I played once and then the game crashed I didnt win anything and played again for whole time I played how to play again tell me please

Comment: Yeti level?  I don't recall there being any yeti level in Diablo 3.

Comment: I asked yeti in pvz2 sry tipped wrong